# How to connect to Azure Cosmos DB Gremlin API via embedded code

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

For now we are using the very simplified and not near reality approach that Azure officially lets one play: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin/quickstart-java.

But we need to use gremlin in a scriptive manner ... like this:

`g.V().has()...`

... not as a string script query that is then submited:

```java
static final String gremlinQueries[] = new String[] {
            "g.addV('person').property('id', 'thomas').as('tom'),
            "g.addV('person').property('id', 'mary').as('may'),
            "g.addE('friends').from('tom').to('may')" };

(...)

for (String query : gremlinQueries) {

   ResultSet results = client.submit(query);
}

for (Result result : resultList) {
   result.toString()
}
```

I already tried to use Tinkerpop Documentation guides:

https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#gremlin-java
https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-gremlin

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but Cosmos DB's Gremlin API is accessed in the same manner as any other gremlin-based graph database (e.g. same SDKs). Also, you linked a few different help articles, but nobody should need to visit/read those to understand your question. What's your specific issue? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: sorry @DavidMakogon if I wasn't clear ... Stephen answered down there ... which seems to be: no solution! :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are asking how to send Gremlin bytecode queries to CosmosDB, but are finding that you can only send strings-based queries. If that is correct, note that CosmosDB does not currently support bytecode based requests, so you are in fact limited to strings. CosmosDB has a long open issue about this [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/439).